# SQl update and select in one query

Tags: mysql

I am having a little trouble with a SQL query task.

The task is to show the current product prices:

```
SELECT prod_id AS 'Product ID', prod_name AS 'Product Description',
       price AS 'Product Price', on_hand AS 'Quantity', supp_id AS 'Suppliers ID' 
FROM products 
WHERE prod_id LIKE '%TA%' 
OR prod_id LIKE '%HP%'
```

The 2nd part of the task is where I have the problem. I need to update the prices by 10% - I can do this with a separate query. However, this is part of my college course and I am being asked to put both the UPDATE and the SELECT (showing the changes) in one query. This is where I'm stuck.

Here is my code so far (I get errors when in the SELECT part)

```
UPDATE products
SET price = price+(price *0.1)
WHERE prod_id LIKE '%TA%'
OR prod_id LIKE '%HP'

SELECT 
prod_id AS  'Product ID',
prod_name AS  'Product description',
price AS  'product Price', 
on_hand AS  'Quantity',
supp_id AS  'Supplier ID'
FROM products
WHERE prod_id LIKE  '%TA%'
OR prod_id LIKE  '%HP%'
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to end a MySQL statement (update, select, delete etc.) you need to end it with a semi-colon (;).  If you add that in after the update, it should work work for you.

As a side note, I've never understood why people would want to do the two things in the same statement, but that's a whole other question and debate.